# Update PeropertyChanged item of external Model (Class library) MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have a **ObservableCollection** of **Chat** class of Telegram library ([TDLib](https://github.com/tdlib/td)) and i cant access to change this class and implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** and *OnPropertyChanged* for peroperies.
and i have a **ListView** in my app (C# WPF .NET Core)

ViewModel:

```
public class ListChatViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ListChatViewModel()
    {
        chats = new ObservableCollection<TdApi.Chat>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TdApi.Chat> chats;
    public ObservableCollection<TdApi.Chat> Chats
    {
        get => chats;
        set => SetField(ref chats, value, "Chats");
    }
}
```

StaticClass:

```
public class Statics
{
    public static ListChatViewModel ListChatViewModel = new ListChatViewModel();
}
```

PageListView.xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv_items" Grid.Row="0" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" VirtualizingPanel.CacheLength="50" VirtualizingPanel.CacheLengthUnit="Pixel" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource listViewItemMainChatListStyle}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" SelectionChanged="lv_items_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel><ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid MinHeight="70" Background="#31394D">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Margin="16,0,0,0" Width="42" Height="42" CornerRadius="42" Background="{Binding Photo, Converter={StaticResource ChatPhotoNullToColorConverter}}"/>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="8,0,8,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Foreground="#CED4E6" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Roboto"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Opacity="0.7">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastMessage.Text}" Foreground="#CED4E6" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,0,0" FontFamily="Roboto"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

PageListView.cs:

```
    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lv_items.ItemsSource = Statics.ListChatViewModel.Chats;
    }
```

Now how i can update LastMessage of Chat?
I use this code for update LastMessage but UI not update

```
   var chat = Statics.ListChatViewModel.Chats.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == updateChatLastMessage.ChatId);
   chat.LastMessage = updateChatLastMessage.LastMessage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right approach here is to create a view model to wrap the `Chat` class (let's say `ChatViewModel`), this way you can encapsulate every Chat property to actually trigger their `PropertyChanged` event on set.

So you'd end up with something like this:

```cs
public class ChatViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly Chat _chat;

    public ChatViewModel(Chat chat)
    {
        _chat = chat;
    }

    public Message LastMessage
    {
        get => _chat.LastMessage;
        set
        {
            _chat.LastMessage = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke("LastMessage");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```